# How to force input autocomplete popup from javascript

Tags: javascript

My idea is to mix two inputs one for user input and second for autocomplete popup.

```css
.ibox {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
}
#i1 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100px;
  z-index:20;
}
#i0 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="on">
  Email: <div class="ibox">
  <input type="email" id="i0" name="email">
  <input type="email" id="i1" name="email">
  </div>
  <br>
</form>


Click on input and you should see autocomplete popup.
```

General questions:

- How to prevent autocomplete popup on white input but leave on gray?
- How to force gray input autocomplete popup when white input clicked
  or some characters was entered? I want hide gray input and use it for autocomplete popup only.

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Thanks, first question can be solved!

Answer (score 0):

you can set [autocomplete="off"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

```css
.ibox {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
}
#i1 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100px;
  z-index:20;
}
#i0 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="on">
  Email: <div class="ibox">
  <input type="email" id="i0" name="email">
  <input type="email" id="i1" name="email"  autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <br>
</form>


Click on input and you should see autocomplete popup.
```

Comment: Yes, first question solved, how about second general question? Force gray input autocomplete popup while user input in white? It means display popup menu.